# How to format returned json response from servlet using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, servlets

I am trying to present the list of users returned from servlet called using jquery ajax. The first script block works perfectly well but could not pass the form parameters like text and dropdown list value but presents the list of users returned from server in well formatted list.

The script that formats the response but cannot pass the form parameters to servlet .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("form submitted");
        $.get('SearchUserServlet', function(responseJson) {
            alert(responseJson);
            alert("inside the servlet");
            var $ul = $('<ul class="list-group">').appendTo($('.well'));
            $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) {
                $('<li class="list-group-item"><strong>').text(item).appendTo($ul);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The second script i tried passes the form parameters properly to the servlet but the response returned from the servlet does not get formatted like the first script does. 
Below is the second script

```
var form = $('#SearchForm');

form.submit(function(){
    type: form.attr('method'),url: form.attr('action'),data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(responseJson) {
        alert(responseJson);
        alert("inside the servlet");
        var $ul = $('<ul class="list-group">').appendTo($('.well'));
        $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) {
            $('<li class="list-group-item"><strong>').text(item).appendTo($ul);
        });
    });
});
```

please help me find the problem in the two scripts so that i can pass the form parameters as well get the response formatted in proper list.
Please review and advice.

Comment: first call in which data is not passed to the server and second call in which form parameters submitted to server but can you provide output/json of second call for which you are getting unformatted response.

Comment: @TechnoCrat ...can u please simplify ..cannot make sense

Comment: please provide json so that it can be validated for cause of unformatted exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this assuming your json strin is jsonString={...,..,..};

```
for(i=0; i<data.jsonString.length; i++) {
    //do your work here with which you are doing inside $.each  
}
```